# How does Guiding Bolt apply Advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, advantage-and-disadvantage

Spells like Guiding Bolt says: next attack roll made against target before the end of your next turn, has advantage.
If there is a party of four, let's say, do all get advantage? Or just the next attack?

Answer (score 15):

Just the very next attack, so only one advantage. This also means the effect is wasted if the next attack already has advantage.